# No action was found on the controller 'Tickets' that matches the name 'CloseTicket'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am writing a webapi project and am receiving the error No action was found on the controller 'Tickets' that matches the name 'TestMethod' whenever I try any of the methods in the controller.

None of the actions in the below controller are working.

I have been googling and have already setup WebApiConfig.cs to add action to the routing.

Is there something else I am missing.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class TicketController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public static ServiceResponse<string> IssueTicket([FromBody]ServiceRequest<TicketRequest> request)
    {            
        return ServiceResponse<string>.WithPayload(ticketID);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public static ServiceResponse<bool> CheckTicketExist([FromBody]ServiceRequest<string> request)
    {            
        return ServiceResponse<bool>.WithPayload(doesExist);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public static ServiceResponse<bool> CloseTicket([FromBody]ServiceRequest<string> request)
    {
        return ServiceResponse<bool>.WithPayload(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public static bool TestMethod([FromBody]string test)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ValutBoy14  What does your URL look like when you are getting this error?

Comment: You can use Attribute Routing to make the things clear.  Also you have to make sure you use System.Web.Http namespace for HttpPost attribute.

Comment: What url are you using to get the "no action was found" error? Why do you have `static` in all your actions? The form post url needs to be yoursite.tld/api/ticket/IssueTicket

Comment: Remove the `static` from your action methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API doesn't consider static methods while selecting actions.

[Reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

> Which methods on the controller are considered "actions"? When selecting an action, the framework only looks at public instance methods on the controller.

Remove the `static` keyword from your controller.